# Target element that is loaded externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollreveal.js

I'm trying to target an element to be used by a ScrollReveal function, the element is being loaded from a different html file called "header.html". Currently, the ScrollReveal effect does not occur, yet elements that are in my index.html do.

JS:

```
sr.reveal('nav', {
    origin: 'left',
    distance: '10rem',
    duration: 900,
});
```

Load function in my HTML:

```
$(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
```

nav is inside header.html

Comment: Where do you call `sr.reveal(...)`? Is it ensured that it is being called after the loading of `header.html` / `footer.html` is done and the elements are present within the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete callback of load() to assure the new content has loaded before you try to work with it

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("header.html", function() {
    // new html has been inserted
    // do what you want with it
    sr.reveal('nav', {
      origin: 'left',
      distance: '10rem',
      duration: 900,
    });
  });

  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```